# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, summation

I'm trying to figure out whether the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ converge uniformly or not.

I've thought about several ways to disprove this, in case it doesn't, such like showing that $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ doesn't converge uniformly to the function $f(x)=0$.

then if : $$ A_n = sup{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}$$ converges to zero, as $n$ goes to infinity, then the original Sum converges. but I've noticed that $f(x)$ (the limit function of the sequence {$f_n(x)$} isn't continuous at all), and its depends on $x$,  and that means that {${f_n(x)}$} doesn't converge to zero. which means  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$ doesn't converge uniformly.

Does my logic make any sense? I'm not sure if this is the right direction to go to. any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of your functions?

Comment: Its not given for some reason .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series diverges if $x \geqslant 1$ by comparison with a divergent geometric series.

Note that for $0 \leqslant x <1,$

$$\left|\sum_{k = n}^\infty\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}\right|\geqslant\left|\sum_{k = n}^{2n}\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}\right|\geqslant \frac{nx^{2n}}{1-x^n} \geqslant nx^{2n},$$

and

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)} \left|\sum_{k = n}^\infty\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}\right| \geqslant \sup_{x \in [0,1)} nx^{2n} = n $$

Alternatively, with $x_n = 2^{-1/n},$ we have

$$\left|\sum_{k = n}^\infty\frac{x_n^k}{1-x_n^k}\right|\geqslant \frac{n}{4} \geqslant \frac{1}{4},$$

and the series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1).$

However, it is uniformly convergent on $[0,a]$ with $a < 1$. Perhaps you can give this part a try.

Comment: did u use here the theorem about the $N$'th rest of the series? and not $f_n(x)$  ?

Comment: Yes -- I'm showing the difference between the limit and partial sum cannot be uniformly small for $n$ sufficiently large.